# Extracting min and max values from different columns in sql

Tags: sql, netezza

I have the following table:

```
Emp_Id    In_Time               Out_time             
10     '2014-07-16 08:25:00'  '2014-07-16 10:25:00'  
10     '2014-07-16 10:35:00'  '2014-07-16 14:42:00'
10     '2014-07-16 15:00:00'  '2014-07-16 16:03:00'
10     '2014-07-16 16:15:00'  '2014-07-16 16:24:00'
```

In this table, the office(in and out), lunch breaks(in and out), coffee breaks etc are recorded in the same columns. 
My aim to find the min value of (In_time) and max value of (Out_time) to record the total time in office.
The final output should be like this :

```
Emp_Id        In_Time                 Out_Time
10           '2014-07-16 08:25:00'    '2014-07-16 16:24:00'
```

I am working on this code:

```
select Emp_Id, min(In_Time) over(partition by Emp_Id) as start, 
max(Out_Time) over(partition by Emp_Id) as stop,
from tablename
where day(In_Time) = day (Out_time) 
group by (Emp_Id, In_Time, Out_time)
```

I am checking if the days are same to ensure that typing errors in entering dates are included in final result.
On doing this, I am getting two four rows with same values. I realize that grouping everything is causing that but Netezza doesn't allow single attribute in group by.
Can someone help me with the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `group by` and `date_trunc()`:

```
select Emp_Id, date_trunc('day', in_time) as date,
       min(In_Time) as start, max(Out_Time) as stop,
from tablename
where date_trunc('day', In_Time) = date_trunc('day', Out_Time)
group by Emp_Id, date_trunc('day', in_time);
```

Comment: In Netezza, you need to group emp_id, in_time, out_time else it gives an error.

Comment: @Jenna . . . Those columns are only arguments to `min()` and `max()`.  They should not be in the `group by`.

Comment: If I only group by emp_id, I am getting an error. The error is asking me to add in_time and out_time in group by since they are present in the select statement.

Comment: @Jenna . . . You also need `date_trunc('day', in_time)`.

Comment: so if I do that, then I get repeating rows